# Count number of sentences which contains words from other list Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, count

I have two lists and I am trying to find the count of words in one list which is contained in other list

sample data

```
list1 = ['apple','orange','ball','peach']
df['list2'] = ['Apples were served as the dessert','They like apples','I prefer oranges to apples.','Tom drank his orange juice','These oranges have gone bad','He could hit the ball, too']
```

My output should be

```
apples 2
oranges 3
ball 1
```

I am able to count by extracting each single string but my list1 has more than 60 words. Is it possible to get the count of all words if this is contained in list2? Thanks in advance

My code

```
df = df[df.list2.str.lower().str.contains('apples')]
```

Comment: "My code" isn't valid Python.

Comment: @ScottHunter - it is valid pandas code

Comment: @jezrael which would require at least require *mentioning* pandas in the question.

Comment: This need fuzzy match as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what your `df['list2']` refers to, but here's a working example:

```
list1 = ['apple','orange','ball','peach']
list2 = [
    'Apples were served as the dessert',
    'They like apples','I prefer oranges to apples.',
    'Tom drank his orange juice',
    'These oranges have gone bad',
    'He could hit the ball, too'
]
# Creating a dictionary of words from list1
word_dict = {w : 0 for w in list1}

# Looping through each word of list1
for w in list1:
    # Looping through each sentence of list2
    for s in list2:
        if w in p:
            # If the word of list 1 is present in the sentence of list2, add 1 to the count
            word_dict[w] += 1
print(word_dict)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It worked great. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If possible simplify problem for also counts by substrings words like `pineapples` are counts like `apple` solution is:

```
from collections import Counter

list1 = ['apple','orange','ball','peach']

a = Counter([y for x in df['list2'] for y in list1 if y in x.lower()])
print (a)
Counter({'apple': 3, 'orange': 3, 'ball': 1})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'vals': list(a.keys()), 'count': list(a.values())})
print (df1)
     vals  count
0   apple      3
1  orange      3
2    ball      1
```

Comment: change one of the apples to pineapples

Answer (score 1):

Using `Series.str.extractall` and `Series.value_counts`:

```
df['list2'].str.extractall(f"({'|'.join(list1)})")[0].value_counts()

orange    3
apple     2
ball      1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

---

**Note**: as mentioned in the comments, the "flexibility" of `str.extractall` comes with a price that it will match any string with "apples" in them. So "pineapples"  for example will be counted as well.

Comment: Same ~ change one of the apples to pineapples, extract with space , will help ~

Comment: See edit @YOBEN_S (ps, again name change :) ?)

Comment: Had space in name , and hard for people to @ me ~  delete the space now ~ ~

Comment: Thank you it works great. I need a relative match not an absolute so  the code works great.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd make a dictionary out of the first list

```
dictOfWords = { i : 5 for i in listOfStr }
```

dictOfWords now loks like this

```
{'apple': 0, 'orange': 0, 'ball': 0, 'peach': 0}
```

Then you can iterate through your list of phrases with a nested for loop

```
for key in dictOfWords:
  for element in list:
    if key in element:
      dictOfWords[element]+=1
```